# How to find the number of times that a substring occurs in a given string (include jointed)?

Tags: string, algorithm, rust

By jointed I mean:

```rust
let substring = "CNC";
```

And the string:

```rust
let s = "CNCNC";
```

In my version "jointed" would mean that there are `2` such substrings present.
What is the best way of doing that in `Rust`? I can think of a few but then it's basically ugly `C`.

I have something like that:

```rust
fn find_a_string(s: &String, sub_string: &String) -> u32 {
    s.matches(sub_string).count() as u32
}
```

But that returns `1`, because [`matches()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.matches) finds only disjointed `substrings`.

What's the best way to do that in Rust?

Comment: https://docs.rs/memchr/2.4.1/memchr/memmem/fn.find_iter.html

Comment: thus I don't know the result for your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is a better algorithm. Here I just move a window with the size of the sub-string we are looking for over the input string and compare if that window is the same as the substring.

```rust
fn main() {
    let string = "aaaa";
    let substring = "aa";

    let substrings = string
        .as_bytes()
        .windows(substring.len())
        .filter(|&w| w == substring.as_bytes())
        .count();

    println!("{}", substrings);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach of iterating over all windows is perfectly serviceable when your needle/haystack is small. And indeed, it might even be the preferred solution for small needles/haystacks, since a theoretically optimal solution is a fair bit more complicated. But it can get quite a bit slower as the lengths grow.

While Aho-Corasick is more well known for its support for searching multiple patterns simultaneously, it can be used with a single pattern to find overlapping matches in linear time. (In this case, it looks a lot like Knuth-Morris-Pratt.)

The `aho-corasick` crate can do this:

```
use aho_corasick::AhoCorasick;

fn main() {
    let haystack = "CNCNC";
    let needle = "CNC";
    let matcher = AhoCorasick::new(&[needle]);
    for m in matcher.find_overlapping_iter(haystack) {
        let (s, e) = (m.start(), m.end());
        println!("({:?}, {:?}): {:?}", s, e, &haystack[s..e]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(0, 3): "CNC"
(2, 5): "CNC"
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab6c547b1700bbbc4a29a99adcaceabe